# Xamarin Universal iOS app runs only on iphone

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2015

I have a Xamarin iOS Universal app with simple forms in a Tabbed Controller (with three Tabs). The IDE am using is Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin in it.

In each tab, I have simple UITextFields and the problem now is they appear only in iPhone in the Main.Storyboard. When I select "iPAD" under "View As", all the UI components disappear. (added screenshots of the IDE below)

Same happens when I run the app on simulators too. The app UI appears on iPhone simulators but not on iPAD simulator.

I understand that I do not need to explicitly do anything to make this run on an iPAD. Please correct me if am wrong, and help me on what to do to make this work.

Thanks.

[image: iPhone5S Screenshot]

[image: iPAD Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set Devices in info.plist as `Universal` ?

[image]

Also in Storyboard, for each of the UI Controls that are removed while selecting iPad check if that UI control is installed for All Size Classes.

Scroll to the bottom of properties Tab after selecting the widget and check if it is wAnyhAny.

[image]

Tutorial for size classes can be found in Xamarin's [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_unified_storyboards/#Size_Classes)

Comment: And Size classes ?

Comment: Size Classes - no I haven't done anything explicit. How/Where do I customize them?

Comment: it is selected as wAnyhAny

Comment: followed the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: @LohithKorupolu Any time :-)